# Web server does not respond to outside network

Tags: apache-http-server, port, webserver

I installed Apache and Phusion Passenger on a Rackspace Cloud server (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), but for some reason I can't access it from an outside machine.

From the local server I get a correct response:

```
root@ttt:/opt# wget http://beta2012.ttt.com/
--2012-09-26 03:12:42--  http://beta2012.ttt.com/
Resolving beta2012.ttt.com (beta2012.ttt.com)... 198.101.xx.xx
Connecting to beta2012.ttt.com (beta2012.ttt.com)|198.101.xx.xx|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 9365 (9.1K) [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'
```

Whereas from my local machine, and from another server, I get the following:

```
root@server:/opt# wget http://beta2012.ttt.com/
--2012-09-26 10:13:42--  http://beta2012.ttt.com/
Resolving beta2012.ttt.com... 198.101.xx.xx
Connecting to beta2012.ttt.com|198.101.xx.xx|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

I can see that the A record must be working, since I get the correct IP. How come Apache responds to local queries, but not to remote?

This is a clean installation, there is almost nothing else on the server, apart from Apache, MySQL server, Git and RVM.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, Rackspace blocks all ports by default on new cloud servers (apart from 22 for SSH obviously).

I had to amend iptables to allow for traffic on port 80, 443, etc.